# Using lower_bound on nested map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map that looks like

```
map<string , map<int,int>>
```

the string contains name of a student, the nested map contains ID as key and age as value. When I print the map, it al prints values as it should.

However, I want to find a students with a certain ID and lower. I tried using lower_bound using:

```
for( auto &x : class ){       
   auto it = x.second.upper_bound(some_number);
   for( ; it != x .second.begin() ; --it){
      cout << x.first << " = " << << it -> first << " " <<it -> second  << endl;       
   }
}
```

This indeed prints right names of students, but their IDs and ages are just zeros or random numbers, what is causing this behavior? It works when I just print it.

I tried to found out about this on cpp map reference but found nothing.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's a strange data structure. One student, identified by his or her name, can have multiple IDs and ages?

Comment: How did you manage to declare a map called `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code solves your problem:

```
for( auto &x : Class ){       
    auto it = x.second.upper_bound(some_number);
    while(it!=x.second.begin()){
        it=prev(it);
        cout<< x.first<< " = "<< it->first<< " "<< it->second<< endl;
    }
}
```

Refer [std::map::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)

What above code does is, first it finds the iterator with id strictly greater than `some_number`. Now because we want to print "students with a certain ID and lower", we print all the id's lower than the return value of `upper_bound`.
The stopping condition is that if iterator is itself `x.second.begin()`, that means now we don't have any id's smaller than it.

---

Plus your data structure is strange, you should have student ID as your primary index.
`map<int, pair<string,int> >` would be more appropriate data structure. (Assuming unique id's which is mostly the case).
Although, you could do lot better using OOP concepts.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the return value of `upper_bound` incase it returns `x.second.end()` (i.e. its not present in the map) ?

Comment: If upper_bound returns `it=x.second.end()`, then `prev(it)` will point to last element in the map. So we print all the id's till `x.second.begin()`

Answer (score 0):

What you see is probably undefined behaviour, [std::map::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) returns also end iterator under some conditions and from your code it does not look like you check for this condition. Also you should not use `class` keyword as variable name for your map, I am preety sure it does not compile. Below is a sample code that should work with no UB and print all IDs less than some number including this ID:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efae1ae4faa3e656

```
map< string , map<int,int>> classes ={ 
    { "k1", {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}  }
};

//int class;

int some_number = 4;
for( auto &x : classes ){       
    auto it_num_end = x.second.upper_bound(some_number); // some numberis just variable that contains number
    for( auto it = x.second.begin(); it != it_num_end ; ++it){
     cout << x.first << " = " << it -> first << " " <<it -> second  << endl;       
    }     
}
```

Comment: This doesn't generate the intended output. When some_number is 0, it still prints `k1 = 1 1`. Expected output should be none.

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani I have updated, if I have not overlooked something its easier than I thought